# Using Argparse to Create Calculator

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am making a basic calculator using argparse. I basically accept some numbers from the command line followed by either add,subtract,multiply,or divide action. I only have the adding part right now.
Here is my code:

```
import argparse
from sys import argv

def get_args(args):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Calculator')
    parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
           help='an integer for the accumulator')
    parser.add_argument('--add',dest = 'sum',help = "Adds the set of numbers")
    parser.add_argument('--subtract', 
                    help = "Subtracts the set of numbers")
    args = parser.parse_args()

def main(argv):
    args = get_args(argv[0:])
    if args.a or args.add:
        return sum(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":main(argv)
```

However, when i input:

```
calculator.py 1 2 3 --add
```

it gives me the error: expected one argument and also, in python there is a function sum(), but is there a subtract,multiply,and divide function as well? If not, then how do i return the sum without using the sum() function. I assume you would use a for loop to cycle through all the numbers?

So using the for loop would be something like this:

```
def main:
    args = get_args(argv[0:])
    if args.a or args.add:
        for row in argv[1:]:
            sum = sum + argv[row]
        print sum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `--add` command-line switch wants to have an argument. Make it a switch instead:

```
parser.add_argument('--add', action='store_true', help="Adds the set of numbers")
```

Note that I removed the `dest` argument, you want the result to be stored in `args.add`, not `args.sum`.

Your `get_args()` function needs to *return* the result of `parser.parse_args()`:

```
def get_args(args):
    # ....
    return parser.parse_args()
```

There won't be a `args.a`, just test for `args.add` only, and you want to sum the `args. integers` attribute, not the `args` namespace object itself. You probably wanted to print the result:

```
if args.add:
    print sum(args.integers)
```

If you wanted to use a loop instead, loop over `args.integers`:

```
if args.add:
    result = 0
    for value in arg.integers:
        result += value
    print result
```

Comment: Yes, but then there is another error: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: @Andy: Read the rest of my answer. You had multiple errors in your program.